# lua how require works

Tags: lua, require

I'm using a graphics library that lets you program in Lua. I have a need for the A* pathfinding library so I found one online. It's just 1 lua file that does the pathfinding and 1 example file. In the example file it uses the object like:

```
-- Loading the library
local Astar = require 'Astar'
Astar(map,1) -- Inits the library, sets the OBST_VALUE to 1
```

I run the script and everything works. So now I add the Astar.lua file to the path location where my graphics engine is running and do the same thing and I get the error on the Astar(map, 1) line:

"attempt to call local 'AStar' (a number value)

Any ideas why I would be getting that error when I'm doing the same thing as the example that comes with this AStar lib?

Here is a little of the AStar file

```
-- The Astar class
local Astar = {}
setmetatable(Astar, {__call = function(self,...) return self:init(...) end})
Astar.__index = Astar

-- Loads the map, sets the unwalkable value, inits pathfinding
function Astar:init(map,obstvalue)
    self.map = map
        self.OBST_VALUE = obstvalue or 1
    self.cList = {}
    self.oList = {}
    self.initialNode = false
    self.finalNode = false
    self.currentNode = false
    self.path = {}
    self.mapSizeX = #self.map[1]
    self.mapSizeY = #self.map
end
```

So note that when I run this from my graphics engine it's returning 1, but when run from the example that it came with it's returning a table, which is what it should be returning. So not sure why it would only be returning 1.

Comment: I notice in the error message `"attempt to call local 'AStar' (a number value)"`, the S is capitalized. Is that a typo on your part or are you perhaps using the wrong capitalization somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How is Astar getting added to the `package.loaded` table for the example script, as opposed to your code?

> QUICK LUA SYNTACTIC SUGAR REVIEW:
>
> - `func 'string'` is equivalent to `func('string')`
> - `tabl.ident` is equivalent to `tabl['ident']`

When you run a script using `require('Astar')`, this is what it does:

- checks if `package.loaded['Astar']` is a non-nil value.

  - If it is, it returns this value. Otherwise it continues down this list.
- Runs through filenames of the patterns listed in `package.path` (and `package.cpath`), with '?' replaced with 'Astar', until it finds the first file matching the pattern.
- Sets `package.loaded['Astar']` to `true`.
- Runs the module script (found via path search above- for the sake of this example we'll assume it's not a C module) with `'Astar'` as an argument (accessible as `...` in the module script).
- If the script returns a value, this value is placed into `package.loaded['Astar']`.
- The contents of `package.loaded['Astar']` are returned.

  - Note that the script can load the package into `package.loaded['Astar']` as part of its execution and return nothing.

As somebody noted in the comments above, your problem may come from loading the module using 'A**S**tar' instead of 'A**s**tar'. It's possible that Lua is loading this script using this string (since, on the case-insensitive Windows, a search for a file named "AStar.lua" will open a file called "Astar.lua"), but the script isn't operating with that (by using a hard-coded `"Astar"` instead of the `"AStar"` Lua is loading the script under).

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `return Astar` at the end of `Astar.lua`.